# Is there a way to install PL/Python after the database has been compiled without "--with-python" parameter?

Tags: postgresql, plpython

Ubuntu 14.04.3, PostgreSQL 9.6

Maybe I can get the plpythonu source code from the PostgreSQL 9.6 source code or somewhere else, put it into the `/contrib` directory, `make` it and `CREATE EXTENSION` after that!? Or something like that.
Don't want to think that PostgreSQL reinstall is my only way.

Comment: Yes, there is. It is necessary first to create an environment variable PYTHON='path/to/python'. Then go to postgres source directory and execute `sudo make distclean`. After that compile Postgres again with parameter “--with-python”, go to `./contrib` and execute `sudo make install`. And finally, execute `CREATE EXTENSION plpython3u;` in `psql`.

Answer (score 2):

you can simply run

## python 2

`sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib postgresql-plpython-9.6`

## python 3

`sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib postgresql-plpython3-9.6`

Then check the extension is installed

`SELECT * FROM pg_available_extensions WHERE name like '%plpython%';`

To apply the extension to the database, use

## for python 2

`CREATE EXTENSION plpython2u;`

## for python 3

`CREATE EXTENSION plpython3u;`

Comment: Beautiful! I've been searching for 3 days.

Comment: For Centos 7, try this
`yum list *plpython*` and then install the correct python. For me this was: `sudo yum install postgresql10-plpython3.x86_64`